# Standard Error: Can it be fitted?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I keep it short and with visuals. Say I've got normal distributed data.

Now after calculating the mean $\mu$, standard deviation $\sigma$ and standard error $s_e$. Plotting the data overlaid by the Gaussian function $g(x) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\,\pi}\,\sigma} \,e^{\dfrac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\,\sigma^2}}$ as you can see:

[image]

I think it fits the data quite well. My only concern is: does a similar function $\bar{g}(x)$ exist that involves the standard error $s_e$?

In $g(x)$ substituting $\sigma$ by  $s_e$ seems wrong because it reminds on an inequality. But ain't that right?

**Edit**

This is what it looks like if I plot $g(x)$ with $s_e$ instead of $\sigma$:

[image]

Could it be true? The probability distribution of the mean. I mean technically it could be, because it should be much smaller, I guess.